# Unable to click on ImageView in Robotium

Tags: java, android, automation, robotium

I have the source code for the ImageView

```
ImageView topbarCalender = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.pf_topbarCalender);
```

I want to click on image using robotium. I used the following code for it

```
ImageButton image1 = (ImageButton) solo.getView("pf_topbarCalender"); 
     solo.clickOnView(image1);
```

Its not working. My test is failing.

Comment: I think you should upload the error logs in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
ImageButton image1 = (ImageButton) solo.getView("pf_topbarCalender"); 
solo.clickOnImageButton(image1);
```

or

```
View view = solo.getView("pf_topbarCalender"); 
solo.clickOnView(view);
```

Comment: there is no method `clickOnImageButton(ImageButton)` in robotium. I am using 5.3.1

Answer (score 0):

```
enterView view = solo.getView("pf_topbarCalender");
solo.clickOnView(view);
```

Some times doesn't work on Android 6. 
And I use next method:

```
solo.clickOnImageButton(index);
```

Parameters:
index - the index of the ImageButton to click. 0 if only one is available

But on different divices image button can have different indexes.

Answer (score -2):

The second approach worked for me:

```
View view = solo.getView(R.id.pf_topbarCalender); 
solo.clickOnView(view);
```

Comment: int parameter in clickOnImageButton is index of the image on the screen and not resource ID

Comment: But, the parameter is still using some ID. It is just plain index like 0,1,2, etc. What do you want to suggest using `R.id.pf_topbarCalender`?